# Shell script grep command -c (count) -- does command-line ordering matter?

Tags: bash, shell, count, grep

just a quick question regarding a doubt. What's the difference between these two:

```
grep "$genre" "$i" | grep "$type" -c
```

and

```
grep "$genre" "$i" | grep -c "$type"
```

Do they do perhaps the same thing?

Comment: POSIX only requires `grep -c "$type"` to work. `grep "$type" -c` is an optional extension; a version of `grep` that doesn't implement that extension will see `-c` as a filename when you put it after the string to search for (or any other positional argument).

Comment: According to guideline #9 of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02, option arguments should precede operands, so the first invocation may be considered non-standard. In practice, your implementation of `grep` probably treats both calls the same way.

Comment: Note that "the first invocation may be considered non-standard" is a fairly meaningless phrase.  Perhaps I ought to say that it is non-standard behavior to treat the two calls the same way, as standard conformant behavior would be to treat `-c` as a filename.

Comment: @LucaGirotti, ...btw, to be clear, this isn't a bash question; `grep` is provided by your operating system, not by bash. Thus, even if you're 100% sure your code will only be run with bash as the shell, that doesn't mean it'll always have a `grep` that behaves the same way as the one you're testing with now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from `man grep`, the `-c` switch belongs to the so-called "General Output Control". Those switches can be placed on different places in the `grep ...` command and this has no impact on the general outcome, so indeed, both lines you mention are equal.

Comment: POSIX only requires `grep -c "$type"` to work. Accepting `-c` as an option rather than an argument in `grep "$type" -c` is a GNU extension; a `grep` that implements only the behaviors the standard requires will treat `-c` as a filename when it isn't prior to the first positional argument.

Answer (score 2):

The POSIX standard-mandated behavior for `grep "$type" -c`, presuming that `$type` does not expand to a string starting with a dash, is to treat `-c` as a filename.

Only nonstandard versions of `grep` (such as the one built by the GNU project and commonly found on Linux systems) will treat `-c` as an option enabling "count" behavior when it isn't before the first positional argument.

It's bad practice to write your scripts to require nonstandard tools unless they gain some concrete benefit from those tools. Use `grep -c "$type"`.